# Get the value from objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was inspecting some code through Firebug's debugger. The value I found is wrapped in `this.executions`. So when I print the value of `temp`

```
var temp = this.executions;
console.log(temp);
```

I am getting output as

```
[Object { context="1461223497558",  value1="TEST1",  value2="TEST2"}]
```

I tried using a for...in loop

```
for(var key in temp) {
  var value = temp[key];
}
```

Though then I am still getting output like

```
Object { context="1461223497558",  value1="TEST1",  value2="TEST2"}
```

I want to extract the values `TEST1` and `TEST2` of the variables `value1` and `value2` key. Any idea how to get them?

Comment: Because you have an array of objects, you need to use 2 loops to get each key and value. If you are sure that the array will have only 1 item then `var temp = this.executions[0];`

Comment: thank you i tried @mimiz solution it worked..

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over keys :

```
var keys  = Object.keys(temp[0]); // As your first temp var is an array
keys.forEach(function(key){
 console.log(key +" : " +temp[key]);
});
```

Or first iterate on executions :

```
this.executions.forEach(function(temp){ // loop over executions
    var keys  = Object.keys(temp);
    keys.forEach(function(key){ // loop over keys
     console.log(key +" : " +temp[key]);
    });
});
```

this will outpout

```
context : 1461223497558
value1 : TEST1
...
```

So now you can do what you want with your data

Comment: Hey thanks for your solution...it worked,sorry i don't have enough reputation otherwise i could have upvoted this answer....

Answer (score 0):

`filter` the object values that start with 'TEST' (ES6):

```
var obj = arr[0];
var out = Object.keys(obj).filter(el => obj[el].substring(0, 4) === 'TEST');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vkzsmc7q/)

Or perhaps a more general function (this time ES5):

```
function extractValues(obj, str) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(el) {
    return obj[el].substring(0, str.length) === str;
  });
}

extractValues(obj, 'TEST'); // ['TEST1', 'TEST2']
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vkzsmc7q/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andy

Answer (score 0):

Note that your first output

```
[Object { context="1461223497558",  value1="TEST1",  value2="TEST2"}]
```

is an array of objects indicated by the square brackets around the object.

Therefore you first need to loop over that array (e.g. by using your for...in loop) and then access the properties of the current object:

```
for(var key in temp) {
  var object = temp[key];
  console.log(object.value1, object.value2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sebastian